# What exactly does the CPU busy light mean?

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, cpu-usage

Most computers have a "CPU busy light" with a sillo icon beside it that lights up periodically. But what exactly does that light mean? Is it turned on when the CPU is in Usage or when the hard drive I/O is up?  I noticed more of a correlation with the disk I/O then the CPU usage.

Comment: The silo light should indicate disk I/O, not CPU activity. It means that your disk is being accessed (read from or written to).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is probably correct then. I always assumed that light was called the cpu busy light but it would make more sense if it was called the hard drive light.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have not seen such a CPU light. Are you sure you do not mean the Hard Drive light. Computers with Hard disk drives often have a hard drive light that goes on periodically when there is hard drive activity. Computers with SSD drives usually do not have such lights.

Comment: Agreed. I have never seen a "CPU busy light". Usually devices will have network and/or HD activity lights.

Comment: Don’t know why but this seems more like a comment rather than an answer to me.

Comment: This was a comment until it was moved from the comments to be an answer. Still looks like a comment, though.

Comment: My comment got 4 upvotes as a comment and the OP agreed it, so I moved it.

Answer (score 1):

The silo light should indicate disk I/O, not CPU activity. It means that your disk is being accessed (read from or written to).

While I actually HAVE seen a CPU activity indicator, it was way back in the 90s using an add-on card that showed part of the address the CPU was accessing, and the card was located inside the computer.